# How to boost performance of Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008r2-express

I use the above server at home and the real/full edition at work.
I have the same database at home and office (small one).

My home computer is i7/4GB/single 2.5" SATA2 HD.

My office computer is i3/8GB/1GB Single 3.5" SATA2 HD.

The office server runs the same queries faster.

Any suggestions regarding how to manually configure the express edition to work faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using it for development only, then install developer edition on your home machine, has the same specs as enterprise edition and is free with MSDN subscription or about $50 otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Fist you need to find out if it SQL server that is the bottleneck or that your code/bad queries/lack of indexing etc. is causing the problem or that it is your hardware

Assuming it really is hardware/sql server because of your office situation....

SQL Server express has hardware limits:

- Single physical CPU, but multiple cores allowable[4]
- 1 GB of RAM (runs on a system with any RAM amount, but uses only at most 1 GB)

So at home your 4gb if memory is not being used...
in that case more/faster disks is probably your best solution or buy another edition (at home you can use developer edition, not expensive)

Apart from that:
Check your code.

Check the query plans to see if you can 'boost' performance with better indexes.

Comment: I didn't know about the 1GB RAM use limit. Thanks.
Is there a configuration possibility on how to use the RAM?

Answer (score 1):

- Use developer edition at home?
- VPN into the office and run remotely?

Comment: No, Express edition. Which is the fastest edition for my hardware?

Answer (score 1):

Express Edition is a Free Edition, I has few limitations
- Max DB Size 10GB
- Only 1 CPU can be assigned

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2010/04/21/database-size-limit-increased-to-10gb-in-sql-server-2008-r2-express.aspx

Do you use Express Edition @ work or Developer / Enterprise Edition

Comment: The office server is Standard x64. The home server is Express x64.

Comment: So you might be losing out on parallelism. Compare execution plans.

Comment: I would like to ask my office system administrator to install a faster server on my home computer. Which edition will be reasonable to ask for (price wise and hardware optimum)?

Comment: I hope you are now aware of SQL Express limitations. Its not apple to apple comparision. You can see how much RAM is allocated, Query processing in terms of time. I hope you are on same code base. Indexes are same in both the code base.

Comment: Also table partitioning, Service broker features would not be available in Express Edition. You can check this link for feature comparision across editions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx

Comment: If you're a developer then get the MSDN version of Standard or Enterprise, whichever your target edition is.

Answer (score 0):

You might use an PrimoCache ... (akia FancyCache) it speed my SQL operations on SQLExpress 2008  by factor of 3. It is still in beta ... but the benefits are huge I am wainting for official version.